# Using scanf and gets simultaneously

Tags: c

I know I am asking basic question. I am having problem with using `scanf` and `gets` in a C program. When ever I am using `scanf`, `gets` is not performing. The example is below:

```
void fun() {
    char str[10];
    printf("Enter the string");
    gets(str);
    printf("Entered string is %s\n", str);
}

int main() {
    int val;
    printf("Enter the value\n");
    scanf("%d", &val);
    fun();
}
```

If I run this program, `gets` is not performing. After Entering the value. It is not waiting to enter the string. Output is `Enter the stringEntered string is`. But if comment the `scanf`, it does wait for input in `gets` and works properly. Can anyone tell me, what did I wrong.

Comment: The Enter key(`\n`) which you press after entering an integer will be present in the `stdin`(Input Buffer) and it is taken up by `gets`. Also never use `gets`.Use `fgets` instead

Comment: The solution is simple: don't `scanf()`.

Comment: What Cool Guy has said. If you are taking input line-wise, it is usually better to read the line with `fgets` and then, if you have to read numbers, parse the line with `strtol` or `sscanf`.

Comment: @TheParamag: What else? Do (f)gets and sscanf from that?

Comment: @PeterSchneider there's nothing that you can do with `scanf()` and not with `fgets()`. The only difference is that `scanf()` is hard to use correctly and it's hazardous.

Comment: @TheParam Hmmm... `int i; scanf("%d", &i);`? And I am not sure why scanf is hard to use or dangerous (more dangerous than the other parts of the macro assembler called C).

Comment: @PeterSchneider `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdint); int i = strtol(buf, 0, 10);` is semantically equivalent (reads an integer) but it additionally *does what the user meant.* It consumes an entire line properly, so there's no need for messing around with extraneous and/or missing whitespace. `scanf()` tries to do two things at once (getting user input **and** parsing it), and consequently fails to do either of them properly. It's hard to use because of subtleties in its behavior (e. g. WRT whitespace), and it's dangerous because it's not typesafe (it's variadic!), and...

Comment: @PeterSchneider ...it's dangerous because e. g. it also hides the fact that one can specify the buffer size when scanning a string (and that buffer size is not even the buffer size but the buffer size minus one, since it doesn't count the 0-terminator, etc.) - All in all, `scanf()` is a horrible function that no professional C programmer should ever use.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the "proper" answer here is simple: Never use `gets`. It's that simple. It has even been removed from C11 standard.

The reason is, you have no way to limit amount of input, so no matter how big buffer you reserve, user can still generate enough input to cause buffer overflow.

You should probably use `fgets`, if you are writing standard C. You should use `getline` if you use *gcc* (like MinGW or Cygwin under Window), or any modern Unix-like OS with support for recent enough POSIX standard.

---

Then to actual question, ignoring problems with `gets`. Problem is, `scanf` leaves rest of the line including the enter press into the input stream. One robust solution is to write a function, which will read input until next newline, something like this untested function:

```
// this function reads given file until newline or end of file or error,
// and returns last value read
int eatLine(FILE *fp) {
    for(;;) {
        int ch = getc(fp);
        if (ch == '\n' || ch < 0) return ch;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if (scanf("%d", &myint) != 1) exit(0); // exit on invalid input
if (eatLine(stdin) < 0) exit(0); // read and ignore rest of the line, exit on eof
```

---

There are other solutions, such as reading a line to buffer and using `sscanf` on it, above is just one easy possibility.

Comment: Sry, but the answer to the question isn't "*Do not use `gets()`*". This is a correct statement, but completely unrelated.

Comment: @alk I augmented the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `scanf("%d", &val)` with `scanf("%d%*c", &val)`.

The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) says that for `%c`:

> The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed.

`%c` therefore matches up the newline after the value and leaves the buffer empty.

That way, when you come to the `fun()` routine, `gets` waits for input.

The `*` in `%*c` means you don't need to store the character in a variable (kudos to @CoolGuy for pointing this out).

Comment: Why do you need to store `\n` in a variable? Why don't you use `%*c`?

Comment: A good idea, and one I wish I had had.  Answer amended accordingly.

Comment: This solution will not suffice if the user typed extra characters before the enter key.  Also checking the return value of `scanf()` is necessary to avoid potential undefined behavior.