# Find index of a given string in an array

Tags: c, arrays

I am writing to write a function findTarget() that searches whether a target name string has been stored in the array of strings.

where nameptr is the array of strings entered by the user, size is the number of names stored in the array
and target is the target string. If the target string is found, the function will return its index location, or -1
if otherwise.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int findTarget(char *target, char nameptr[][80], int size);
int main()
{
    int num, i;
    char target[100];
    char names[10][100];
    printf("Enter no. of names:");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("Enter %d names: ", num);
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", names[i]);
    }
    printf("Enter target name: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(target);
    printf("findTarget(): %d", findTarget(target, names, num));

}

int findTarget(char *target, char nameptr[][80], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(target,nameptr[i]) == 0)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I do aware that using gets() is not recommendation, but we shall leave that aside. Somehow it only works if the target I am finding happens to be at index 0. If it is in other indexes, it fails.

Comment: Can you try it again but declaring nameptr parameter of findTarget as [][100] instead of [][80] ? The dimensions of your parameter don't match.

Comment: Stop lying to the function you're calling. You claim the incoming arrray is `char (*)[80]`, but you pass a `char (*)[100]`. The strides are different. If your compiler didn't at least warn you about this, crank up your warnings. If it *still* doesn't warn you, get a new compiler. And you can add `fflush(stdin)` to `gets()` in the list of things not to do.

Comment: Ok, the dimensions was the issue here

Comment: When compiling with `gcc` I get the warning "warning: passing argument 2 of 'findTarget' from incompatible pointer type / note: expected 'char (*)[80]' but argument is of type 'char (*)[100]'" -- which I fixed *immediately*. And the program ran as it should. Reverting it to your original, it does not.

Comment: You don't need the information about string length, you could just have `int findTarget(char *target, const char ** nameptr, size_t name_count)`

Comment: @Coconop `char (*)[N]` is *not* synonymous with `char **`.

Comment: @WhozCraig agreed, but it can be used in the OP case without harm, no ?

Comment: @Coconop No. They're completely different. One is an array of arrays, the other an array of pointers, and arrays are *not* pointers.

Comment: a duplicate to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26815982/using-scanf-and-gets-simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the function is declared with second parameter as pointer to first element of an array of type `char [80]`

```
int findTarget(char *target, char nameptr[][80], int size);
```

However inside main you pass an array defined such a way that it has element's type `char[100]`

```
char names[10][100];
```

Thus the function has undefined behaviour.

Redeclare the array in main like

```
char names[10][80];
```

Take into account that you should check the entered value of `num` that shall be less than or equal to 10.

As for me I would declare the function the following way

```
size_t findTarget( const char nameptr[][80], size_t size, const char *target );
```

As for function `gets` it is not now a standard function because it is unsafe.
From the C Standard

> removed the gets function ()

You can use for example `fgets` instead.

Also you could use standard C function `bsearch` declared in header `<stdlib.h>` if the array is sorted.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void *bsearch(const void *key, const void *base,
size_t nmemb, size_t size,
int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

Answer (score -2):

The solution to above program can be as follows:

```
printf("Enter target name: ");
    getc(stdin);
gets(target);
```

Well apart from the

> nameptr[][80]

correction all over.

It has something to do with gets function., for which it has already been deprecated.

```
gets(target);
```

There is conflict in data read/write pipe while performing a read from STDIN in between scanf and gets usage.

If we just replace the statement

```
gets(target)
```

with

```
scanf("%s", target)
```

it works absolutely fine

As per strace logs

```
read(0, try
"try\n", 1024)                  = 4
lseek(0, -1, SEEK_CUR)                  = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
write(1, "Enter target name: findTarget():"..., 35Enter target name: findTarget(): -1) = 35
exit_group(16)                          = ?
+++ exited with 16 +++
```

After reading the last name through scanf, the program is trying to read again through STDIN via gets command where it finds ESPIPE error and than misbehaves.

Comment: `gets` and `scanf` do different things; your version won't work for names that contain spaces. Also both of your examples have no protection against buffer overflow.

Comment: Sir I understand you are very particular about the corner cases but the actual problem is different to which you haven't actually looked at.